# Using Private Temporary Table with ODP.NET

Tags: .net, oracle, temp-tables, odp.net, odp.net-managed

I can't find much infromation on this but I think it's not going to be possible as ODP.NET doesn't seem to let you execute multiple statements as a single command.

If I had the following query

```
CREATE PRIVATE TEMPORARY TABLE ora$ptt_Stops
(
    MachineStopID    NUMBER,
    LineID           NUMBER
)
ON COMMIT DROP DEFINITION;

INSERT INTO ora$ptt_Stops
SELECT MachineStop.MachineStopID,
       Line.LineID
FROM Line
INNER JOIN LkLLS ON Line.LineID = LkLLS.LineID
INNER JOIN MachineStage ON LkLLS.LineSection = MachineStage.LineSectionID
INNER JOIN MachineStop ON MachineStage.MachineStageID = MachineStop.MachineStopID;

SELECT MachineStopID,
       LineID
FROM ora$ptt_Stops
```

Is it possible to execute this as a single command in ODP.NET?

Attempts at the moment give this error.

```
"ORA-00922: missing or invalid option"
```

Comment: Try under single transaction. Should work

Comment: You mean, create a transaction and execute each command seperatley, not together?

Comment: Yes. if you create transaction, you can execute commands one by one under same transaction. In oracle it is not possible to execute multiple commands, unless you wrap them into executable block like the stored procedure or anonymous block.More over, any DDL commands commit data.

Comment: Thanks, that's all I wanted a concrete answer on.

Comment: Sorry @Brandon Billingham, I misunderstood what you were trying to do.  I withdraw my answer.